# Windows 10 stuck at restart after SSD clone

Tags: windows-10, boot, reboot, samsung-ssd

So I recently upgraded to `SSD` from `HDD` for my OS and successfully cloned my `Win10`. I can log into win10 and everything works just fine. So far so good. Now the problem is, when I try to restart my PC, from within the Windows desktop (from start menu), its stuck at the logo screen after shutting down. I have to manually turn off the power button and start back on to reboot the OS. Restart option no longer works. What's going on? I know something might have got corrupted during clone process. How fix it?

Is there a windows repair tool I can use to fix boot issues?

I did notice I still have the old EFI System partition on the old OS HDD. Not sure if that would be the culprit. But disconnecting the old HDD didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Did you keep the old HDD connected to the system after cloning?

Comment: @user1686 -  I formatted my original OS partition. now its just free space. Yes my old hdd is still connected as I have multiple partitions in it.

Comment: Can you try (temporarily) disabling the old HDD in the firmware (UEFI/BIOS) or physically disconnect it?

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Disconnected the old HDD. still no luck.

Comment: OK, so now we can narrow down the problem to something in the Windows installation. Perhaps running the usual error correction and system integrity tools is the troubleshooting starting point.

Comment: But also updating UEFI and the SSD's firmware, if available, is among the things I would do.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - please check the updated post regarding EFI partition.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I ran chkdsk and sfc/ scannow, both were successfull but didnt fix the problem.

Comment: Didn't you cloned that partition also? Perhaps you should. Keeping the old one shouldn't be a problem if both drives are connected (and it boots correctly to the new system partition in the new drive) but then how could you have tested whether the problem persists on reboot without actually booting? It can't boot without the ESP...

Comment: @ChanganAuto - you are right, I can boot into the SSD OS just fine, so the old EFI shouldn't be a problem, I just have to remove the old EFI as it's no longer needed. I don't understand whats the difference between boot and restart as it affects only restart mode. I tried running bootrec/fixBoot and I got access denied error. I ran fixMBR and rebuildBCD successfully. So not sure what else to do. Also UEFI is already updated.

Comment: After 3 - 4 hard resets does it enter the Safe Mode? What if you try Clean Boot approach?  What if you force it to boot to Safe Mode using Settings --> Recovery --> Advanced Startup Options?

Comment: I tried booting from USB drive > fixboot, fixmbr, rebuildBCD, nothing worked. Recreated the boot files in EFI partition, that didn't help either.